uwsgi Emperor mode and systemd
I recently created two working configurations for starting uwsgi in Emperor mode with systemd. With the first configuration, the socket is created by uwsgi –
Configuration 1
# /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi-django.service
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI for Django
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
Restart=always
User=www-data
Group=www-data
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/webproject.ini
[uwsgi]
socket = /run/uwsgi-django/webproject.socket
chdir = /var/www/webproject/
module = webproject.wsgi
processes = 10
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum = true

– while the second one uses a socket unit (the uwsgi config file is identical):
Configuration 2
# /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi-django.service
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI for Django
After=syslog.target
Requires=uwsgi-django.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
Restart=always
User=www-data
Group=www-data
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi-django.socket
[Unit]
Description=Socket for uWSGI for Django
PartOf=uwsgi-django.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/uwsgi-django/webproject.socket
SocketUser=www-data
SocketGroup=www-data
SocketMode=0660

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

While both of configurations work fine with a single app, I have two questions:

According to the uwsgi docs, the socket parameter in webproject.ini should not be necessary ("When using Systemd socket activation, you do not need to specify any socket in your uWSGI configuration; the instance will inherit the socket from Systemd."), but removing the parameter in configuration 2 causes an error message ("The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket."). Why is that?

With configuration 1, separate sockets for diferent uwsgi vassalls can be defined in the respective .ini files, which is not possible with configuration 2. Is this a problem for running multiple apps, and is there any advantage to configuration 2 (i.e. using a socket unit instead of configuring sockets via uwsgi)? Creating separate sockets via systemd can be accomplished with template units –


Configuration 3
# /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi-django@.service
[Unit] 
Description=uWSGI for Django (%i) 
After=syslog.target 
Requires=uwsgi-django@%i.socket 
 
[Service] 
ExecStart=/var/www/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --master --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/%i.ini 
Restart=always 
User=www-data 
Group=www-data 
KillSignal=SIGQUIT 
Type=notify 
NotifyAccess=all 
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi 
#StandardInput=socket 
 
[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target 

# /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi-django@.socket
[Unit]
Description=Socket for uWSGI for Django (%i)
PartOf=uwsgi-django@%i.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/uwsgi-django/%i.socket
SocketUser=www-data
SocketGroup=www-data
SocketMode=0660

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

– but not in Emperor mode as far as I can see.
